# makefile fortran multiple directories

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

This has been asked many times but from none of the answers can I figure out how to do it.
Simply put, I have directory structure: `SRC/` for all `*.for` and `*.f90` files, `BLD/` for all files needed for building (that is `*.o` and `*.mod`) and `lib/` for necessary libraries that need to be linked.
I want to build all source files in the `SRC/` directory and put `*.o` and `*.mod` to the `BLD/` directory while keeping the executable in the root where `makefile` is. I don't want to have multiple makefiles. The current `makefile` that does not work is below. I think that one issue there are lines that refere e.g. `$(BLD)/$(objects)` which probably expands to `BLD/nrtype.o nrutil.o nr.o mtypes.o polint.o polyin2.o a.o` but I am not really sure, and I am just trying and erroring since I do not have enough knowledge and the manuals are not clear for me to be able to figure it out. In one of the trials, `*.mod` some got to `BLD/` some stayed in the root, it seems that the rules do not work I think they do.

```
# Compilation related variables
SRC     = src
BLD     = build
LIB     = lib
FC      = gfortran
LDFLAGS = $(LIB)/asm_functions.o
FFLAGS  = -O0
# the name of the output executable
target  = a
# all objects to generate
objects = nrtype.o nrutil.o nr.o mtypes.o polint.o polyin2.o a.o
#
modules = nrtype.mod nrutil.mod nr.mod mtypes.mod
# set module dependencies
nrtype_mod   = polint.o polyin2.o
nrutil_mod   = polint.o polyin2.o
nr_mod       = polin2.o
mtypes_mod   = a.o
# set default target
default: $(target)
# add dependencies to the targets
$(nrtype_mod):  nrtype.mod
$(nrutil_mod):  nrutil.mod
$(nr_mod):      nr.mod
$(mtypes_mod):  mtypes.mod
# compile modules
$(BLD)/%.mod: $(SRC)/%.f90 $(BLD)/%.o
    $(FC) -c $(FFLAGS) -o $@ $<
# compile old fortran files
$(BLD)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.for
    $(FC) -c $(FFLAGS) -o $@ $<
# compile new fortran files
$(BLD)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.f90
    $(FC) -c $(FFLAGS) -o $(BLD)$@ $<
# link everything
$(target): $BLD/$(objects)
    $(FC) -o $@ $(FFLAGS) $^ $(LDFLAGS)

# cleaning up   
clean:
    rm -f $(BLD)/$(objects) $(BLD)/$(modules)

clobber: clean
    rm -f $(BLD)/$(target)

.PHONY: default clean clobber
```

---

### Update

I edited the `makefile` to the form:

```
# Compilation related variables
SRC     = src
BLD     = build
LIB     = lib
FC      = gfortran
LDFLAGS = $(LIB)/asm_functions.o
FFLAGS  = -O0
# the name of the output executable
target  = a
# all objects to generate
objects = $(BLD)/nrtype.o $(BLD)/nrutil.o $(BLD)/nr.o $(BLD)/mtypes.o $(BLD)/polint.o $(BLD)/polyin2.o $(BLD)/a.o
#
modules = $(BLD)/nrtype.mod $(BLD)/nrutil.mod $(BLD)/nr.mod $(BLD)/mtypes.mod
# set module dependencies
nrtype_mod   = polint.o polyin2.o
nrutil_mod   = polint.o polyin2.o
nr_mod       = polin2.o
mtypes_mod   = a.o
# set default target
default: $(target)
# add dependencies to the targets
$(nrtype_mod):  nrtype.mod
$(nrutil_mod):  nrutil.mod
$(nr_mod):      nr.mod
$(mtypes_mod):  mtypes.mod
# compile modules
$(BLD)/%.mod: $(SRC)/%.f90 $(BLD)/%.o
    $(FC) -c $(FFLAGS) -o $@ $<
# compile old fortran files
$(BLD)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.for
    $(FC) -c $(FFLAGS) -o $@ $<
# compile new fortran files
$(BLD)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.f90
    $(FC) -c $(FFLAGS) -o $@ $<
# link everything
$(target): $(objects)
    $(FC) -o $@ $(FFLAGS) $^ $(LDFLAGS)

# cleaning up   
clean:
    rm -f $(BLD)/$(objects) $(BLD)/$(modules)

clobber: clean
    rm -f $(BLD)/$(target)

.PHONY: default clean clobber
```

While with this modification the build is successful, it is still not obeying orders. Specifically, `*.mod` files are being generated where the `makefile` is but I found in the meantime that it is `gfortran` who is disobedient and for `mod` files the output directory is controlled by some other switch. Nevertheless:

Other things that are not clear:

1. Should the lines look like:

   $(BLD)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.for
   $(FC) -c $(FFLAGS) -o $@ $<

Or

```
%.o: %.f90
    $(FC) -c $(FFLAGS) -o $(BLD)/$@ $(SRC)/$<
```

or is it the same (i prefer the second one for readability).

2. Why the line such as

   nrtype_mod   = polint.o polyin2.o

do not need to be prepended by the paths? Or do they have to be (but it built correctly). This is where it is very confusing.

The maual would really benefit from some basic examples of a full makefile.

Answer (score 0):

> I think that one issue there are lines that refere e.g. `$(BLD)/$(objects)` which probably expands to `BLD/nrtype.o nrutil.o nr.o mtypes.o polint.o polyin2.o a.o`

You are exactly correct in your assessment here.

You can use a GNU make function like [`addprefix`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html#index-addprefix) to fix this.

It would be useful to understand what part of the manual you had trouble understanding, so it can be improved.

Comment: I updated the question since, too much text to fit here. Still does not work the way I want. Additionally, is it reasonable to try to make a `makefile` for `debug` and `release` in a single makefile? (I guess the only difference is the `FFLAGS`)